# Failure adding assembly to the cache Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, gac, windows-xp-sp3

i am trying to add an assembly to the GAC but the error indicates that **"Failure adding assembly to the cache: Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected options. Use an administrator ommand prompt to complete these tasks."**

I am using Windows XP SP3 and user account type is Administrator. Please refer to the image below.

TIA

[image: Please refer to the image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZXpc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by additional commands via command prompt

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>runas /user:computerName\administrator cmd**

[image: Check this out]

Answer (score 1):

You are administrator on your machine but you don't run the visual studio command prompt (or cmd.exe) as an admin ...

Comment: I am running it as administrator by doing the right click, run as, both in cmd.exe or vs command prompt